# Change the order that an IPTABLE CHAIN is read (Using Fail2Ban)

Tags: iptables, firewall, port, fail2ban, icmp

I have some experience using iptables and fail2ban.
Both are working as they should, but I would like to optimize the way packets are "DROPed" when IP & port probing occur.

Fail2Ban is doing a good job of blocking IPs that are trying to access various ports (i.e. SSH, MySQL, etc).

However, once an IP is blocked on a specific port (i.e. port 22 for SSH), the HOST is still reachable via ICMP, even thought Fail2Ban has added a "DROP - all" condition to iptables.

I may be wrong, but I think it has to do with the order in which iptables is reading the Fail2Ban CHAIN.

This is what `iptables -L` reveal (IPs and DNSs have been replaced):

```
user@ SERVER > iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
fail2ban-SSH  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  10.10.10.1/25  anywhere
fail2ban-SSH  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
fail2ban-SSH  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp any
ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     ah   --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251         udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain fail2ban-SSH (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  badip.baddomain.org  anywhere
DROP       all  --  299.299.299.11         anywhere
DROP       all  --  prober.hackers.com  anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

**As well, here is my `iptables` file as a point of reference**:

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-securitylevel
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:fail2ban-SSH - [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
#
#
#
-A INPUT -j fail2ban-SSH
-A FORWARD -j fail2ban-SSH
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p ah -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -d 224.0.0.251 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
COMMIT
```

As you can see, there is a line that ALLOWS ICMP:

```
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp any
```

This is done on purpose as I have a need for legitimate users to be able to ping certain servers.

You can see in my iptables file, I have added the "fail2ban-SSH" CHAIN ahead of the others in the hopes that it would get read before all other rules, but that did not work.

My goal would be to DROP ANY request from an IP that Fail2Ban has blocked for any reason, including ICMP requests.

Is there a way to configure iptables to read the Fail2Ban rules, before all other CHAINS and rules, so that I can truly block and IP on all ports & protocols?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, IPs in your SSH jail should be blocked from all ports on the system and should not be able to ping you. All other IPs should be able to ping.

To ban an IP from all ports, you'll need to set up your SSH jail to use the iptables-allports action configuration. You can configure whether to use DROP, REJECT, etc. in /etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-blocktype.conf

```
[sshd]
enabled  = true
action   = iptables-allports[name=sshd]
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 5
findtime = 300
bantime  = 7200
```

If you also want to prevent this specific IP from pinging you while allowing anyone else who isn't in the SSH jail to ping, you will need to add another action to your SSH jail.

- Make copies of both iptables-allports.conf and iptables-blocktype.conf.
- Give the files new names, such as: iptables-blockping.conf and iptables-blocktype-ping.conf.
- Open iptables-blockping.conf and update the [INCLUDES] section to point to iptables-blocktype-ping.conf.
- Open iptables-blocktype-ping.conf and change the blocktype to `REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited`.

Jails can have multiple actions, so directly below iptables-allports[name=sshd], list the name of your new action configuration file, iptables-blockping.conf.

This should work for your purposes - IPs in your SSH jail will have specific entries in iptables to reject ping requests. These rules will be read after your rule to allow pings.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, this is exactly what was missing from my information!  I was not aware that Fail2Ban Jails can have multiple actions.